# What video game is Billy Batson playing in Shazam! Fury of the Gods?

Tags: game-identification

In *[Shazam! Fury of the Gods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shazam!_Fury_of_the_Gods)* (2023 movie), Billy Batson (played by Asher Angel) plays a modern military-themed first-person shooter console game, in which the player character’s objective is to rescue hostage soldiers in a partially destroyed building. He fails to rescue the hostages and sees a message that says “Hostages Killed — Mission Failed”. The game’s graphics look like those from early to mid 2010s games to me.

Clips and screenshots of the game being played:

[image: animated GIF of the game]

<sub>Click/tap on an image below to view the higher-resolution, original image.</sub>

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

##### What video game is Billy Batson playing in *Shazam! Fury of the Gods*?

Comment: I'm getting fairly strong "fake game/made for the movie" vibes.  But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: No UI visible other than the crosshair? That's not something I'd expect from a real game in the genre. Should be ammo & hp indicators at minimum...

Comment: @TimmyJim It really doesn't look like a real game to me either.  Like the graphics also look really bad for what seem to be Xbox One controllers. As Toby mentioned the UI screams "fake".  And for me, theres something about how quickly the "Hostages Killed" comes up that just doesnt seem like a real game's response.

Comment: also, two players, one POV from an FPS? yeah, looks really fake